# Problem 50 in GRE Practice book: Ideals of a ring

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

The [GRE Practice book](https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_math.pdf) includes this problem (#50).

> Let $R$ be a ring and let $U$ and $V$ be (two-sided) ideals of $R$. Which of the following must also be ideals of $R$ ?
>
> I. $U + V = \{ u + v : u \in U\,\, \text{and}\,\, v \in V \}$
>
> II. $U \cdot V = \{ uv : u \in U\,\, \text{and}\,\, v \in V \}$
>
> III. $U \cap V$
>
> (A) II only
>
> (B) III only
>
> (C) I and II only
>
> (D) I and III only
>
> (E) I, II, and III

### My thoughts so far

Choice III seems to be correct according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Ideal_generated_by_a_set but I don't quite understand why, and I'm not sure how to think about choices I or II.

Comment: The first step is to show that they're subgroups of $R$. Can you do that?

Comment: @leibnewtz Do you mean I should show that $U$ and $V$ are subrings of $R$? Or do you really mean subgroups? If you do mean subgroups, which is the group operator?

Comment: Actually, it is given information that both $U$ and $V$ are ideals of $R$ which means that they are subgroups with the additive operation. right?

Answer (score 0):

> [...] I don't quite understand why, and I'm not sure how to think about choices I or II.

You are presented with three sets.

They will either satisfy the [defining characteristics of an ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Definitions) or they won't.

You simply have to check the properties.

Actually there is a shorter, [simpler list of criteria](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/142475/29335) to check that some people call "the ideal test."

---

Simply apply it to each of these sets. The ones that are ideals pass straightforwardly. In the one that doesn't pass, you will get stuck, and then it's time to think about a counterexample for a while.

In fact, there are more than one posts existing already that explain the one that isn't an ideal. There are also posts that explain why the other two are ideals. You should try out the criteria for yourself for a while, and if you're still having trouble after a day or two, look for solutions.

Comment: This is very helpful; thank you. I can now show that I and III are indeed ideals, and I've failed to show that II is an ideal. But I'm stuck on a counterexample. Do you have another hint to help me proceed? Is there an etiquette for how I should show my attempt-in-progress?

Comment: @JoshOrndorff Well, can't believe I didn't respond to this comment so long ago. It wasn't an intentional omission! You found the right one. For a counterexample, I'd just advise looking at something simple like $\mathbb Z[x,y]$ and the ideals $(x)$ and $(y)$.